# Como colocar um evento OnClick chamando uma function javascript em um Link dentro de uma GRIDVIEW em asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um formulário contendo um botão que abrirá uma popup de consulta. Nessa popup, faço uma consulta passando como parametros nome e cpf onde o retorno da consulta, cria um gridview onde cada registro contém um link que retornará os dados para um java script. O meu problema é que não consigo colocar um link dentro da grid passando os parametros.

Abaixo minha grid e a chamada da função javascript:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwPES" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PES_ID" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="gvwPES_PageIndexChanging" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cod." Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("PES_ID") %>    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <itemtemplate>
              <%#Eval("PES_NM") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Enviar" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:informa_pessoa(<%#Eval("PES_ID") %>,<%#Eval("PES_NM") %>,<%#Eval("PES_DOCID") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("PES_END") %>,<%#Eval("PES_CEP") %>,<%#Eval("PES_CID") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("PES_UF") %>,<%#Eval("PES_FON") %>,<%#Eval("PES_FAX") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("PES_INSCE") %>,<%#Eval("PES_INSCM") %>,<%#Eval("PES_BAI") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("PES_DOC_IDENT") %>,<%#Eval("CON_ID") %>,<%#Eval("CON_NM") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("PES_TP") %>,<%#Eval("PES_NUM_END") %>,<%#Eval("PES_COMPLEMENTO")%>,
                                                     <%#Eval("TCP_TP_LOGR") %>,<%#Eval("PES_TP_APR") %>,<%#Eval("SUS_LIM") %>,
                                                     <%#Eval("SUS_DT") %>,<%#Eval("PES_INST_PROT") %>)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Próximo" PreviousPageText="Anterior" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function informa_pessoa(parametros da popup...) {

           Código da popup...
           window.close();
       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer chamar função `javascript` no click é com o atributo `OnClientClick`, apesar de que minha recomendação seja você adicionar um evento de click no **CodeBehind** e chamar por lá passando os atributos.

Caso queira continuar no onClientClick seria algo assim:

```
<asp:Button ID="Enviar" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("informa_pessoa({0}, '{1}') ", Eval("PES_ID"), Eval("PES_NM")) %>' />
```

Arruma seus `Eval`, coloca do conforme meu exemplo.

A melhor forma seria usando `RowCommand`, exemplo:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Enviar" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Enviar" 
                CommandArgument="<%# Eval("PES_ID") %>"
                Text="Enviar" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

E adiciona na *GridView* o evento `onRowCommand="gvwPES_RowCommand"`

Finalizando o método

```
protected void gvwPES_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Enviar")
    {
        var pesId = e.CommandArgument;

        // o que vc precisa fazer
    }

}
```

Comment: Evite longas discussões nos comentários; esta conversa foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25067/discussion-on-answer-by-maicon-carraro-como-colocar-um-evento-onclick-chamando-u)

Comment: @bfavaretto É que ele não tinha pontuações suficientes para participar do chat, dessa forma esse é o único jeito de eu tentar ajudar ele. De qualquer forma obrigado pela "limpeza".

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, fiz o que você falou, e deu para fazer as conversões perfeitamente. Porém ele não esta passando os dados da página filho para a página pai. Essa form de consulta é uma popup. Nela eu posso utilizar o metodo javascript self.opener.document? e se eu setar os parametros com o mesmo nome que é recebido na  function, ele já pega automatico?

Comment: Não seria `window.opener.document`?

Comment: é o self.opener mesmo!

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Passei a chamada da função conforme você comentou no chat da seguinte forma:               Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "informa_pessoa", parametros, true);
 onde retornou  string <script>informa_pessoa(4, 204058, FRANCISCA GERMANO DOS SANTOS SANTIAGO , 78288002315,'','','','','','','','','','', 0,'', 002,'','', 24,'', 0,'', 0)"</script> onde retorna o seguinte erro: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Comment: você precisa ter os parâmetros entre aspas simples '' se não vai dar problema tipo no FRANCISCA GERMANO

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, era isso mesmo. Só mais uma coisa. Quando você abre uma popup, porque que tudo que eu faço nela tipo abrir uma grid, ele abre em uma nova janela?

Comment: Não consegui entender muito sua questão, não quer abrir outra pergunta com isso?

Comment: E se resolveu seu problema nessa questão, fazendo favor marque como resposta certa :)

Comment: Blz... Valeu pela ajuda!